# Mouth Deformations when Posing

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, rigify, pose-mode

I'm having issues with the corner of the mouth section of my rig. When I move the jaw up and down I get sharp deformations in the mesh that looks like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How do I fix this?

The file is located here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CRH3UKruwP-dywsDXeF-6dn-580X6jYG/view?usp=sharing

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weights are quite sharp try **Smooth Vertex Weights**

[image]

[image]

---

BTW - If you check vertex per vertex in this jaw area, single vertex affected by 20 groups? It doesnt sounds good :)

[image]

Comment: Smoothing out the weights and removing the extra vertex groups worked perfectly. Thank you!